# How to call a second fuction in the background while running the main program?

Tags: python, concurrency, process, subprocess

I have one program that collects data from a websocket, processes the data and if some conditions apply I want to call another function that does something with the data.

This is easy enough, but I want the program that collects the data from the websocket to keep running.

I have 'fixed' this quite ugly by writing the data in a database and letting the second program check the database every few seconds. But I don't want to use this solution, since I occasionally get database is locked errors.

Is there a way to start program B from program A while program A keeps running?
I have looked at multi threading and multi processing, and I feel this could be a way to solve it, but while I grasp the basic of that, it is still a bit too difficult for me to use.

Is there an easier way? and if not should I study multi threading or multi processing more?

(or if anyone knows a good guide/video, that would be great too!)

Comment: StackOverflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. Asking for recommendations is also off-topic here.

Comment: @Hans, does the solution I proposed fits your needs?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest launching a worker thread, waiting for data to process. Main thread listen to websocket, and send data to worker through pipe.

The logic of worker is:

```
while True:
    data = peek_data_or_sleep(pipe)
    process_data(data)
```

This way you won't get thousands of workers when incoming traffic is high.

So the key point is how to send data to worker, usually a pipe or message queue.

I've used Celery with RabbitMQ as message queue. Send data to Celery from Django server, and Celery call your function from another process.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example assuming you are using asyncio for WebSockets:

```py
import asyncio
from time import sleep

async def web_socket(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    for i in range(5):
        await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
        await queue.put(f"Here is message n°{i}!")
    await queue.put(None)

def expensive_work(message: str):
    sleep(0.5)
    print(message)

async def worker(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    while True:
        message = await queue.get()
        if message is None: break
        await asyncio.to_thread(expensive_work, message)

async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    
    await asyncio.gather(
        web_socket(queue),
        worker(queue)
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The `web_socket()` function simulates a websocket listener which receives messages. For each received message, it put it in a queue that will be shared with another task running concurrently and processing the message.

The `expensive_work()` function simulates the processing task to apply to each message.

The `worker()` function will be running concurrently to the websocket listener. It reads values from the shared queue and process them. If the processing is really expensive (for instance a CPU-bound task) consider running it in a `ProcessPoolExecutor` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) how to do that) to avoid blocking the event loop.

Finally, the `main()` function creates the shared queue, launches the two tasks concurrently with `asyncio.gather()` and then awaits the completion of both tasks.

---

If you are using threads and blocking IO, the solution is essentially similar but using `threading` `Thread`s and `queue.Queue`. Beware not to mix multithreading and asyncio concurrency, or search on how to do it properly.